# How to interpret my stacktrace?

Tags: java, websphere, openjpa, load-time-weaving, compile-time-weaving

I use IBM RAD 8 and deploy to websphere and then I get this stacktrace:

```
ERROR ArendeProcessLoginServlet:142 - Fel i ArendeProcessLoginServlet, performTask(): 
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The type "class se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.entity.Anstalld" has not been enhanced.
javax.ejb.EJBException: See nested exception; nested exception is: <openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The type "class se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.entity.Anstalld" has not been enhanced.
<openjpa-2.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1141200 fatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: The type "class se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.entity.Anstalld" has not been enhanced.
    at org.apache.openjpa.meta.ClassMetaData
```

What does it mean? What steps should I take to resolve the error?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I would assume OpenJPA is expecting some annotation on the class `se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.entity.Anstalld` which you don't have.

Comment: This answer might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2127277/771837

Comment: Thanks guys. Now I learned what the trace means. I actually only had to restart my server to fix this, so it was was probably a matter of having reloading new classes that I got from the VCS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your model class 'se.prv.pandora.arendeprocess.entity.Anstalld' hasn't been ehnanced. See [this](http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-ant.html) link on how to enhance model classes in openjpa before they can be used by your application.

Comment: woops I've made 'this' clickable now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It now works. I only had to restart the server since it seems that my problem was reloading new versions of classes from version control.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Now that you mentioned it, I remember running into similar problems when I used to work on RAD 7. Sometimes, refreshing the project (selecting it and hitting F5) or cleaning the server's working directory helps as well.